# Excel VBA - Set Hyperlink Display Text

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

**Intro:** I export marketing reports for click-through rates which give me URLs of products from my company's website. I want a column which displays the product title as the display text, while maintaining the text as a hyperlink. This is to create the datasource for a mailmerge utilizing the column with the product title/hyperlink.

I have a VBA macro set up like this:

```
Sub ClickableLinkTitle()
'Dim List As Integer, result As String
'Range("$G$2:$G$158").value = List
'Range("$H$2:$H$158").value = result

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim value As String

j = 7

For i = 2 To Rows.Count
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 6)) Then
        value = Cells(i, 6).value

        If value = "http://example.com/products/db.asp?prodID=1" Then
            Cells(i, j).value = "Product 1"
        ElseIf value = "http://example.com/products/db.asp?prodID=2" Then
            Cells(i, j).value = "Product 2"
        ElseIf value = "http://example.com/products/db.asp?prodID=2" Then
            Cells(i, j).value = "Product 3"

        '(ect....until Product 400-and-something)

        End If              
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This produces a Compile error stating Procedure too long. I've already broken it up into multiple subs, but I don't want to continue having to do that. It's also so manual it almost defeats the purpose of creating the macro. But since I have already created it, and have the relationship for the urls & the product titles established I don't just want to throw it away.

**Question:** What is the most efficient method of creating a column displaying the Product Title that is a hyperlink to the product on my company website?

**Brainstorming efforts:** 
Extract the url & the product titles from my macro and put them into two separate columns then figure out a macro to combine the two.

Ping the url and retrieve the page title from the html header tag to display as the product title.

Comment: I would try and find the last used row in that column rather than searching through the entire 1048576 rows of the worksheet.  Something similar to `With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With`

Comment: A Select Case for `value` might also help

Comment: @NinjaLlama I don't really understand what this would do? Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: it would determine the last row used and then you could use that stored value in `For i = 2 To Rows.Count` instead of looping until Rows.Count

Comment: I added 40000 entries to column F and then timed your code against mine.  My suggestion will have diminishing returns depending upon how many rows of data you actually have, but using 40000 entries my code ran in 0.39 seconds versus the 3.32 seconds that your code ran.

Answer (score 0):

if your product names are following the pattern you show you could do something like this

```
For i = 2 To Rows.Count
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 6)) Then    
            Cells(i, j).value = Replace(Replace(Value,"http://company.com/",""), "-", " ")    
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: The product URL is a query string 
http://example.com/products/db.asp?prodID=1
http://example.com/products/db.asp?prodID=2
http://example.com/products/db.asp?prodID=3
So I would assume your answer would still work. I'll have to try it, thank you Thorarins!

Comment: Now that I think about it, I don't think that would work.